# Kotlin: Why does override with additional optional arguments not work?

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, overriding

I'm trying to override the `toString` function of a data class with a custom `toString` that has optional arguments, but it is not working as expected:

```
data class LatLong(
    val latitude: Double,
    val longitude: Double
    ){
    
    // Override keyword not allowed by compiler here
    fun toString(decimals: Int = 5) =
        "${"%.${decimals}f".format(latitude)}, ${"%.${decimals}f".format(longitude)}"
}


fun main() {
    println(LatLong(-123.0, 49.0))  // prints: "LatLong(latitude=-123.0, longitude=49.0)"  i.e. does not call custom toString
    println(LatLong(-123.0, 49.0).toString())  // prints: "LatLong(latitude=-123.0, longitude=49.0)"  i.e. does not call custom toString
    println(LatLong(-123.0, 49.0).toString(decimals=5))  // prints: "-123.00000, 49.00000"
}
```

Question is how *should* I override it to get the behaviour that you'd expect (i.e. all 3 calls above should use the custom method)?.

I could obviously add

```
    override fun toString() = toString(decimals=5)
```

But this means defining the default argument twice which is a recipe for future bugs.  Of course I could define the default as a constant and reference from both `toString`a, but it seems messy.  It is surprising `LatLong(...).toString()` does not call the new method.

**What is the "Kotlinic" way to handle this?**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare the default value twice. Just declare it in the `toString` override, rather than in your own `toString`'s parameter list:

```
override fun toString() = toString(decimals = 5)

// make this a required parameter
fun toString(decimals: Int) =
    "${"%.${decimals}f".format(latitude)}, ${"%.${decimals}f".format(longitude)}"
```

Of course if you have more format options this would get a bit complicated, but you can always just wrap everything in a (data) class, and end up with a single parameter.

```
data class FormatOptions(
    val decimals: Int = 5,
    val someOtherOption: Int = 10
)

override fun toString() = toString(FormatOptions(/* ... */))

fun toString(options: FormatOptions): String = TODO()
```

Just by the way, the parameter list of the call `toString()` *exactly* matches the parameterless `toString` overload declared automatically by the data class. On the other hand, it only matches the one you declared if it considers optional parameters. So the compiler has very good reasons to prefer to resolve `LatLong(...).toString()` to the parameterless `toString` method, instead of the one you declared.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Yep, as you say, it works so long as there is only one argument.  I still say it makes no sense that the `toString(...)` with all-default arguments does not override `toString()`, and there is no way to call it while leaving all defaults in place, but I guess that is just an unfortunate Kotlin design decision.  Will mark as the correct answer unless something else comes up soon.